Intune Deployment cant find PowerShell Modules
I am trying to use Dell Bios Manger to push bios passwords to users. I have deployed the manager already to all machines. Now I deployed another script to modify the password of the bios so end users are unable to change boot order.


$DellModulePath = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DellBIOSProvider"

cd $DellModulePath
# Import the DellBIOSProvider module
Import-Module DellBIOSProvider

try {
    # Check if the admin password is set by retrieving the current value
    $isPasswordSetItem = Get-Item -Path DellSmbios:\Security\IsAdminPasswordSet
    $currentValue = $isPasswordSetItem.currentValue
    
    if ($currentValue -eq "False") {
        # If the password is not set, define the new admin password
        $adminPassword = "PASSWORD"
        
        # Set the admin password
        Set-Item -Path DellSmbios:\Security\AdminPassword -Value $adminPassword
        
        # Verify if the admin password is set
        $isPasswordSetItem = Get-Item -Path DellSmbios:\Security\IsAdminPasswordSet
        $currentValue = $isPasswordSetItem.currentValue
        Write-Output "Is Admin Password Set: $currentValue"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Admin password is already set."
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
}



I push this as a win32 app via Intune - and also via scripts in intune becuase I could get more info on its failure.
When ran as a script on a test machine target I get this error:
"ResultDetails"="{\"Version\":1,\"SigningCode\":649,\"EncryptionCode\":633,\"SigningMsg\":\"(Success) AccountId:DELETED,PolicyId:DELETED,Type:1,Enforce: Enforcement1. OSVersion:10.0.22631,AgentVersion:N/A \",\"EncryptMsg\":\"run in legacy mode\",\"ExecutionMsg\":\"Import-Module : The specified module 'DellBIOSProvider' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any \\r\\nmodule directory.\\r\\nAt C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Intune Management \\r\\nExtension\\\\Policies\\\\Scripts\\\\80c42a96-31c9-49df-83a8-5f1cb24b6d83_d8b4c279-babd-4f48-8de0-6e09d55e43f1.ps1:12 char:1\\r\\n+ Import-Module DellBIOSProvider\\r\\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\r\\n    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (DellBIOSProvider:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException\\r\\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand\\r\\n \\r\\nGet-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'DellSmbios' does not exist.\\r\\nAt C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Microsoft Intune Management \\r\\nExtension\\\\Policies\\\\Scripts\\\\80c42a96-31c9-49df-83a8-5f1cb24b6d83_d8b4c279-babd-4f48-8de0-6e09d55e43f1.ps1:16 char:26\\r\\n+ ... swordSetItem = Get-Item -Path DellSmbios:\\\\Security\\\\IsAdminPasswordSet\\r\\n+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\r\\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DellSmbios:String) [Get-Item], DriveNotFoundException\\r\\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand\\r\\n \\r\\n\\r\\n\"}"

It seems to be trying to find the module in this folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Intune Management Extension\Policies\Scripts

But that isnt where I specified the script to drill to:
${env:ProgramFiles}\Dell\PowerShell\Modules\

What is this behavior? How do I get it to access the right folder?
